# Safari unreasonably slow rendering SVG files

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

I have an application where I load different SVG files into an object and perform operations on them using JS. The code is all correct and works perfectly across all latest browsers, even IE11, with the single exception of Safari (including Safari on iOS and wkhtmltopdf).

When the application runs in Safari, performance on the SVG objects is abysmal. This includes initial page loading and changing the `data` attribute of the host `<object>`. Basic tasks like using `setAttribute` while looping over SVG elements can hang the application for minutes.

The application is entirely dependent on SVG interactivity so this is a major issue for me.

I'm pretty sure yet this is something related to the content of the SVG files. I've been playing around with simplifying the files to see if a particular type of SVG feature is to blame (patterns, styles, embedded images, `<use>` elements, etc) and while things do get faster as things like images are ripped out I haven't found any primary culprit yet and I can't really remove features without breaking the app anyway.

One odd thing I noticed is that changing from a "simple" SVG to a complex one is faster than the other way around. It seems like Safari has trouble cleaning up the complex object when it's not needed.

I've set up a demo page at the following link:

http://www.flooradvisor.com.au/shapes/backend/tests/webkit-svg-change-src.html

If anyone can help me understand why Safari hates my SVG files and what I can do about it that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Over 2 years later, did you manage to get some clarity on this? We are currently working on a project which makes heavy use of D3 to render graphs, and crucial aspects of the app break entirely on Safari. If the rendering does not grind to about 10 FPS, the browser crashes. We have tried both Chrome and Firefox on the same hardware, and they both perform stellarly - no lag whatsoever, and even low resource usage. There is clearly something wrong with Safari.

Comment: @csvan: Sorry csvan but "July 13" doesn't mean July 2013, it means 13 Jul 2015 (two months ago, not two years). Anyway, in the end I convinced the client to give up on iOS/Safari support and that wasn't an easy "fix" to sell. Kinda surprised that Apple built an empire around graphic designers but have so far failed to reliably implement this 15 year old open standard (maybe because they don't own it?). The only advice I can offer is to avoid SVGs with external graphic objects as I have a suspicion the `<use>` tag triggers race conditions when loading external content on Apple browsers.

Comment: @csvan - Also, minimising use of `setAttribute` helped a little for reasons I'm entirely at a loss to explain.

Comment: After having to do an annoying Safari-only work around because `foreignObject` is all screwed up in Safari (especially hosting a canvas), I also ran into this poor SVG rendering issue. Not only is the rendering slow, but for some odd reason the slow rendering is causing keyboard events to be repeated. (Problem visible here, unless another fix has been found by time you click on this: https://shetline.com/orloj/)

Comment: **SVG performance in Safari still awful:** When resizing the viewport of a weppage with full-width sections with a SVG `.background-pattern { background: url("data:image/svg+xml,... inline SVG") }` created with https://doodad.dev/pattern-generator/ on macOS 11 Big Sur this is butter smooth on Chrome 114 but quite stuttering on Safari 16.5 (whereas usually Safari outperforms Chrome in performance).